# Angular Twilio Video Call not working on safari only

Tags: angular, typescript, twilio

Have been working on Twilio video call project in Angular.
Have integrated video call using Example Twilio project I had downloaded from the net but I have lost the link where I had downloaded. I currently have the code with me.
The Twilio example is working perfectly on every browser except Safari 11.1.2.

I get an error:-

```
[Error] ERROR – Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.video.selectedId')
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:740178
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:492888
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491931
t@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:13976
u@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491723
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:787884
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:492888
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491931
t@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:13976
u@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491723
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:790850
    pi@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:563186
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:528342
__tryOrUnsub@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:498817
next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:497994
_next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:497036
next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:496708
next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:502152
emit@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:527818
onAddRoom@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:723    572
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:727210
pi@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:563186
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:640692
onInvokeTask@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:532149
runTask@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:2980
invokeTask@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js    :1:8878
m@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22323
k@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22548
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.video.selectedId')
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:740178
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:492888
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491931
t@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:13976
u@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491723
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:787884
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:492888
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491931
t@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:13976
u@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491723
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:790850
pi@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:563186
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:528342
__tryOrUnsub@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:498817
next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:497994
_next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:497036
next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:496708
next@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:502152
emit@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:527818
onAddRoom@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:723572
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:727210
pi@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:563186
https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:640692
    onInvokeTask@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:532149
runTask@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:2980
invokeTask@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:8878
m@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22323
k@https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22548P     — polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:13030(anonymous function) —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:12120s —     main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:491827onInvoke —     main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:532234run —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:2314(anonymous function) —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:13775onInvokeTask —     main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:532150runTask —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:2981g —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:10063invokeTask —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:8902m —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22324k —     polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22549
    yn (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:529138)
handleError (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:529335)
next (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:538767)
(anonymous function) (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:528038)
__tryOrUnsub (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:498818)
next (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:497995)
_next (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:497037)
next (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:496709)
next (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:502153)
emit (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:527819)
run (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:2314)
onHandleError (main.ca36bd91f9f93196cd42.js:1:532517)
runGuarded (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:2532)
e (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:11659)
microtaskDrainDone (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:11708)
g (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:10130)
invokeTask (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:8902)
m (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22324)
k (polyfills.06d8ebfbbb480cd38b03.js:1:22549)
```

[Twilio Sample Zip](https://experttalk.softprodigy.in/ClientAppCompressed.zip)

Can someone please help and resolve the error in the example project so I can integrate in my project.

Comment: I can only assume in this case that the error is coming because `this.video` is not set, thus calling `selectedId` on it leads to it being undefined. I can't tell much more though. It looks like your stack trace is from a production bundle of your application, you might find more information if you try to use your site in Safari in development mode. Perhaps you could try that and share the error message from that?

Comment: any luck!? facing the same issue with safari...

Comment: No. Had contacted with twilio also, but they suggested using JavaScript example as that was working in safari. We built a work around. Built full functionality into plan JavaScript example provided by twilio. And redirected safari users to that code on for joining the video call.

Comment: Hi, can anyone point me to the source of angular twilio video application or sample?